# Relocation Error when activating Conda environment

Tags: path, conda, environment, relocation, mamba

In a Unix system, I use `mamba activate` to activate a Conda environment where Tensorflow 2.11.0, version for GPU, is present. After the environment is activated, if I digit `ls` or similar commands, I get the following error:

> relocation error: /lib64/libacl.so.1: symbol getxattr, version ATTR_1.0 not defined in file libattr.so.1 with link time reference

The error disappears with:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/ssl/lib/
```

so I copied it in my `.bashrc`, but also after refreshing it, the problem is still there.

I was expecting that having the right path exported in `.bashrc` would have made it "permanent", but apparently it does not work when I activate the environment.

Additional information:

1. `which ls` shows:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
        /usr/bin/ls
```

2. In my mamba environment I never installed `coreutils`, `libacl` and `attr`, indeed, if I digit `mamba env list` I cannot see them.
3. `mamba repoquery whoneeds attr --tree` gives me the following output:

```
attr[2.5.1]
  └─ libcap[2.67]
     ├─ libsystemd0[253]
     │  ├─ pulseaudio-client[16.1]
     │  │  ├─ pulseaudio[16.1]
     │  │  │  └─ qt-main[5.15.8]
     │  │  │     └─ pyqt[5.15.7]
     │  │  │        └─ matplotlib[3.7.1]
     │  │  └─ pulseaudio-daemon[16.1]
     │  │     └─ pulseaudio already visited
     │  └─ pulseaudio-daemon already visited
     ├─ pulseaudio-daemon already visited
     └─ libudev1[253]
        └─ pulseaudio-daemon already visited
```

Comment: What does `which ls` show? Does the environment have `coreutils`, `libacl`, or `attr` installed? Maybe you could share the environment? (`mamba env export`) Or get a tree of why, for example, `attr` is installed: `mamba repoquery whoneeds attr --tree`. Please edit the question body to add all this information.